# How to repeat jQuery press row effect in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

There is a table I have found in codepen: 
https://codepen.io/nikitamarcius/pen/LQOaxd

It is code example:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="text-uppercase text-bold">id selected: {{selected}}</div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label class="form-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll" @click="select">
    <i class="form-icon"></i>
  </label>
                </th>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="i in items">
                <td>
                    <label class="form-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" :value="i.id" v-model="selected">
                        <i class="form-icon"></i>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>{{i.id}}</td>
                <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                <td>{{i.email}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And script part:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: () => ({
        items: [
            {
                id: "id1",
                name: "John Doe",
                email: "email@example.com"
            },
            {
                id: "id2",
                name: "Jone Doe",
                email: "email2@example.com"
            }
        ],
        selected: [],
        selectAll: false
    }),
    methods: {
        select() {
            this.selected = [];
            if (!this.selectAll) {
                for (let i in this.items) {
                    this.selected.push(this.items[i].id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can see that while hover on it, an active column is indicating by a special color. What is the way to take data from a row the similar as it is made using jQuery events code: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

So, once again, I want to make a functionality based on Vue.js code which will **return row's data when I press in any area of that row.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a click event listener for each row at `tr`, and pass the row data to the event handler, for instance:

```
<tr v-for="i in items" @click="clickedRow(i.name)">

methods: {
  ...
  clickedRow(i) {
    alert('clicked row' + i)
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgQWZY

Comment: Please note that you may need to catch click events on, for example, the checkbox and prevent propagation when using this approach. Otherwise you will end up with this handler being called while also having the checkbox checked for example.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is EXACTLY what I had looking for. Wish you all the best in your projects! Appreciate your support!

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thank you very much for your comment!